# AngularJs chaining promisses and using notify

Tags: angularjs, promise, angular-promise

When I have multiple promises and resolve them one by one I can easily get notifications from each promise while it is being resolved.

However it seems that when I chain promises or use the `all()` method then some notifications are getting lost. I am wondering why this is the case.

Here is an example. Lets say I have two async functions that return a promise, do some work and while doing this they call notify one or more times:

```
function returnsSomePromise1() {...; setTimeout(...); return promise;}

function returnsSomePromise2() {...; setTimeout(...); return promise;}
```

Now I have three options to resolve the promises:

```
var promise1 = returnsSomePromise1();
var promise2 = returnsSomePromise2();

//Option 1: Resolve separate
promise1.then(...);
promise2.then(...);

//Option 2: Resolve chained
promise1.then(promise2).then(...);

//Option 3: Resolve with all()
$q.all([promise1, promise2]).then(...);
```

In each then function I attach a simple function to log the notifications to the console:

```
.then(..., ..., function(update) { console.log(update); });
```

Now I find it interesting that all three options yield different results when it comes to notify. The first one prints all notifications of each async operation. The second option only prints the notifications of the first promise, the last option using the `all()` method does not print any notifications at all.

Can anyone explain what is causing these differences and if it is possible to get notifications when using `$q.all()`?

Comment: $q.all returns a array of all responses $q.all().then(arrayOfResponses) you can use a for loop to iterate over them.

Comment: I think thats not correct, `all()` takes an array of promisses and returns a promise, resolving this promise with `then()` passes an array of responses to the first callback function. At least thats how I am using it.

Comment: yes for sure $q.all returns a promise

Comment: Notification is a completely borked (and broken API) like you sort of started noticing. I strongly recommend you avoid it. There is no good way to aggregate notifications in the general case.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 will fire the promises in parallel, they will be resolved individually.  If you want to do something after both have resolved you would need to add extra logic using this option

Option 2 will fire the promises one after the other.  This is useful if `promise2` depends on something from `promise1`.

Also, You code should be `promise1.then(returnsSomePromise2).then(...);` it wants a function in `.then()` where before it was getting a promise (`promise2`).  The function it calls will return the promise and it will chain it.

Option 3 will fire them in parallel and resolve a function when both (all) have been completed.  `$q.all()` can take an array OR an object.  In the case o an array, which you have in your example.  The function passed to `.then()` will be passed an array.  The array lines of with the order of the promises passed to `$.all()`.

```
$q.all([promise1, promise2]).then(function(result){
    var promise1Result = result[0];
    var promise2Result = result[1];
})
```

If you pass an object, with named keys, you will get an object back in the function passes to `.then()`.  The keys will line up with the object passed to `$q.all()`

```
$q.all({myFirstPromise:promise1, secondPromise:promise2}).then(function(result){
    var promise1Result = result.myFirstPromise;
    var promise2Result = result.secondPromise;
})
```

Comment: Sorry but this does not answer my question. I already know how to use each of the three option and also what their differences are. My question was about why the notifications yield different results in all three versions and why in particular some notifications are getting lost.

Comment: This answers "Can anyone explain what is causing these differences and if it is possible to get notifications when using $q.all()? " Please read the answer explanation for option 2 more carefully. It explains why it is getting lost. Also I noticed you were using setTimeout, there is an angular function, $timeout, that returns a promise.